# The yii search criteria

Tags: yii

I'm a yii programmer...

I have 2 variables and I want to check if the first variable exists in the the city column and the second variable in type "OR" category column.

I did this and it doesn't work :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
'condition'=>'published="true"'
));

if(isset($_GET['city']) || isset($_GET['word']))
{
   if(!empty($_GET['city']) )
      $criteria->addSearchCondition('city',$_GET['city'] , true, 'AND');
   if(!empty($_GET['word']) ){
      $criteria->addSearchCondition('type',$_GET['word'] , true, 'OR');
      $criteria->addSearchCondition('category',$_GET['word'] , true, 'OR');

   }
}
```

And only rows with published=true will be displayed...

As a result i get rows that doesn't meet my criteria..

Where is the problem please help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since addCondition is used to attach the new condition with the old condition with the operator given by you and you want to have c1 AND c2 OR c3, your second operator should be the and-operator.